# Use <input> to get property value if property not set in Ant?

Tags: eclipse, ant

I have an Ant target `Clean` which is normally called by another target `Build` (all from within Eclipse). Build sets a parameter/property `system` whether we're talking about the Live/Test system.

But sometimes I might want to run the `Clean` target directly. How can I make this target prompt the user using an `<input>` *only* if `system` is not set?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the `<input>` task already behaves as you'd like:

> Since Apache Ant 1.6,  will not prompt for input if a property
>   should be set by the task that has already been set in the project
>   (and the task wouldn't have any effect).

From the [Ant `<input>` task documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/input.html).

Answer (score 0):

May be inside your `Clean` target, you can use `fail` unless ant task to check system property is set or not, like:

```
<fail unless="system" message="system property needs to be set for directly running clean target, like -Dsystem=neededValue"/>
```